# FMX: Fill whole bitmap with a background color

Tags: delphi, canvas, bitmap, firemonkey, graphic

I want to create a `TImage` component and fill the image with a background color. However my code is a bit longer than I have expected.

1. I have to set the width and height of bitmap.
2. I have to calculate the rectangle of the whole bitmap canvas.

If I remember correctly, in old Delphi versions, I can use `FloodFill` to fill the whole image with particular color. So I think I have definitively missed something.

Can someone figure out how to fill background color with simpler code?

```
Image := TImage.Create(nil);
Image.Position.X := 100;
Image.Position.Y := 100;
Image.Width := 500;
Image.Height := 500;
Image.Bitmap.Width := Trunc(Image.Width);
Image.Bitmap.Height := Trunc(Image.Height);
with Image.Bitmap.Canvas do
begin
  BeginScene;
  try
    Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Black;
    FillRect(RectF(0, 0, Image.Bitmap.Width, Image.Bitmap.Height), 0, 0, [], 1.0);
  finally
    EndScene;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You would do well to stop using with. What you need here is a local variable Bitmap so you only need to write Image.Bitmap once. Try not to repeat yourself in that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no FloodFill in FMX. But you can use `Clear(TAlphaColors.Black);` in order to fill the entire bitmap with a color.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Another thing in my original question is that I have to set the dimension of the bitmap. I do not understand why it is necessary. A `TImage` can hold only one bitmap. Should the bitmap not the same size as the image component?

Comment: On a retina display, the image might need to have a different size than the control. But in this case they still could have set a default size for the bitmap.

Comment: Why would retina make a difference?

Comment: If I run stanleyxu2005's example code on a retina device, I get a black rectangle (that is half the size of the image) centered in the Image control. You'd have to multiply the size of the image with Image.Scene.GetSceneScale (don't forget to check if Image.Scene is Assigned) or use the WrapMode.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why you have to set the Bitmap dimensions is becouse the Bitmap size is not necessary the same size as TImage. You can have smaller or larger Bitmap than TImage and then use one of WrapModes to determine how will that image be rendered to TImage:

The WrapMode property should be one of the constants defined in the TImageWrapMode type:

- iwOriginal: displays the image with its original dimensions.
- iwFit: best fit (keeping image proportions--the ratio between the width and height) for the TImage rectangle. Default.
- iwStretch: stretches the image to fill the entire rectangle of this TImage component.
- iwTile: tiles the TImage image to cover the entire rectangle of the TImage component.

As for calculating rectangle for the whole bitmap. If you want your bitmap to have the same size as TImage then you can easily read TImage.ClipRect.

ClipRect is generally the rectangle which represents the inner part of the control that you are able to render on. On controls that have borders like TPanel for instance ClipRect dimensions are smaller than the whole control dimensions.

And as it was already stated by Sebastian you can quickly fill the entire Bitmap surface background with a single color by using TBitmap.Clear method.

Comment: Thanks for very detailed and educational answer. I use code completion to find suitable property of `TImage`, but I was so blind to see `ClipRect`.

Comment: ClipRect might not give you the desired result on a retina device.

Comment: Why not? ClipRect is size representation of Clip area of a controll expressed in Pixels.

Comment: On a Retina device four pixels of the bitmap will be painted into one "pixel" in ClipRect coordinates of the form. So the bitmap will not fill the entire TImage. Try it on the iPad simulator if you don't have a retina device.

Comment: I would try it out but I only have Delphi X6 Proffesional which doesen't alow me to compile for mobile platforms. I would need athleast Enterprise version or Mobile Addon. But why would be four pixels of the Bitmap painted into one pixel in ClipRect coordinates of the form?

Comment: Maybe this is clearer: On retina every point in user space (as returned by `ClipRect` is backed by four pixels. I think you should ask a new question if you need a better explanation.

Comment: If that is true then FireMonkey is even wose that I imagined as it doesent alow you to make a true HD interface which will make use of full retina screen resolution.

Comment: It works the way it does *because of* Retina support.